# Convert string to Ordered Dictionary

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary

Convert a string to Ordered Python Dictionary. **Given a string that has key and value fields. Value is enclosed in single quotes.**

Example 1:
 Input String: `"Field1:'abc',Field2:'b,c,d',Field3:'d,b,c'"`
 Output dictionary: `{'Field1':'abc', 'Field2':'b,c,d', 'Field3': 'd,b,c'}`

Example 2:
 Input String: `"Field1:'abc',Field2:'HH:MM:SS',Field3:'d,b,c'"`
 Output dictionary: `{'Field1':'abc', 'Field2':'HH:MM:SS', 'Field3': 'd,b,c'}`

I have tried split by ',' and json loads. But, I am facing problems with both cases. "I am not looking for code but an approach".

Comment: Why so many downvotes ?

Comment: @MohamedALANI Presumably because Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
input_st = "Field1:'abc',Field2:'HH:MM:SS',Field3:'d,b,c'"

output_st = {item.split(":")[0]:":".join(item.split(":")[1:]).replace("'", "") for item in input_st.split("',")}
```

outputs :

```
{'Field1': 'abc', 'Field2': 'HH:MM:SS', 'Field3': 'd,b,c'}
```

Kind of ugly but it does the job.

Comment: For this case(input_st = "Field1:'abc',Field2:'b:c,d',Field3:'d,b,c'"), it is not working. Sorry, I should have posted this in the question itself.

Comment: I have updated question now! Once again, I apologize for my mistake.

Comment: @VenkataGogu I updated my answer too. It does the job :)

Comment: @VenkataGogu No worries ! Good luck with that